# How do I get subset of the elements within a list without loosing the elements' name?

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list, (e.g. A) which contains number of elements.  Each element has the same dimension (e.g. 100 x 200).  I have a vector, idx, with a length of 100, same number of row as the elements within the list.  I want to create a new list which is a subset of list A, by for example having idx==1.  I have used lapply and it seems to work but I have lost of element names within the list.  Can you please suggest a better way to achieve this?  Many thanks

```
 # Generate a list A
 A = list()
 for (i in 1:26){
   A[[LETTERS[i]]] = matrix(runif(100*200,0,1),100,200)
 }
 # Generate a vector with 100 elements with integers between 1 and 5
 idx = sample(1:5, 100, replace=T)
 # Create subset list B from list A, where rows are idx==1
 B = lapply(1:26, function(x) A[[x]][idx==1,])
 # However, in list B, I have lost all the element names
```

Comment: Try `lapply(A, function(x) x[idx==1,])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to loop through the `list` and subset it

```
B1 <- lapply(A, function(x) x[idx==1,])
```

Checking if the results from the OP is the same

```
names(B) <- names(A)
identical(B, B1)
#[1] TRUE
```